# C++ Assigning a value to char *argv[] from inside a program

Tags: input, program-entry-point, argv

The customary way of passing values through argv in this declaration

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
```

is to pass it from your console through argv array into a program. I came across a situation where I wanted to achieve something different as follows. The program has the usual

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
```

declaration and inside my program I have a

```
function void foo(argv[1], 0).
```

Here is the layout and flow of my program's logic:

```
program ggg.cpp
     :
void foo(char* x, int y) {
     :
}//end foo
     :
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     :
   foo(argv[1], 0);
     :
}//end main
```

(1) My normal method. Normally, when I compile the ggg.cpp program and my console input is:

**ggg.exe .**     *//the second input is a dot "."*

the program runs fine (because argv[1] = '.' inside the program)

(2) However, I wanted to get innovative and execute the program as:

**ggg.exe**    *//here, the dot is not included*

so that inside the program, I can assign the dot to argv[1] but I kept getting errors - no matter how I try other variations of the assignment statement.

By the way, I tried the assignment statement

```
argv[1]='.';
```

inside the main program (in method (2)) but it didn't work. I got an error message.

**Background Information.** I used to be very good in programming in my hay days but now I have forgotten a lot of things because I left coding for a very long time to do other things.

Comment: `foo_param = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : '.'; foo(foo_param);`

Comment: Thx Todd for ur suggestion but it didn't work. It had errors. Here's how I tried to implement ur ternary version (? :) of the if-else statement:  Here's how I implemented ur suggestion:  `char path2[1000];  
  string x = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : ".";  
  strcpy_s(path2, "");  
  strcat_s(path2, x); /*<- squiggly error appeared on strcat_s*/  
  foo(path2, 0);`  and I got an error on strcat_s on line 4

Comment: You'll figure it out.